# java regex for iraq phone number

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match this phone number pattern:

- it always starts with 07
- then it is followed by a number from this range (3-9)
- and it must be 11 chars

example :
07902848117

07796938209

07302819248

Comment: `^07[3-9]\d{8}$` should do it.

Comment: @Monkeyzeus, just curious, let's say data falls between a line then as you have given ^ and $, will it find the data ? For example: https://regex101.com/r/5pYg5b/1/

Comment: @Deep Let's say that I guessed that OP needs a validator and not an extractor so that a user must enter a number in the given format or be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this, it should work.

"07[3-9][0-9]{8}"  

What this mean is,   
07 - it tries to find literally 07  
[3-9] - then followed by 3 to 9, only one time
[0-9] - then followed by 0 to 9  
{8} - text previous to this should has at least 8 characters.
```

Comment: in some cases, the phone number starts with +964 or 00964  so it will look like this +9647708654312 what is the regex for that

Comment: @Abdalla add `\+?` to make add an optional leading plus symbol.

Comment: Are you aware that this will erroneously match stuff like `solve 6565465+07445213654857`